# What does $\overline{L}^*$ signify?

Tags: formal-languages, notation

Suppose that $L$ is a language.

- What does $\overline{L}^*$ signify?
- Is $\overline{L^*}$ the same as $(\overline{L})^*$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think the question should have been "Is $\overline{L^\ast} = \overline{L}^\ast$?" The answer here would be "no" since for $L = \varnothing$ we have $\overline{L^\ast} = \Sigma^+ \neq \Sigma^\ast = \overline{L}^\ast$.

Comment: There's no difference between $\overline{L}^*$ and $(\overline{L})^*$; they are the same expression, just with parentheses added.  It's like asking whether there is a difference between $(1+2)$ vs $1+2$; or a difference between $(1+2)+3$ vs $1+2+3$.  Is this *really* what you wanted to ask?

Comment: Just to avoid all misunderstandings, I've included *both* interpretations of the question.

Comment: I do think the original question about the meaning of $\overline L^*$ makes perfect sense. We apply two unary operators (star and complement) to a language, both written on separate positions (right-above and above). There is no a priory order they are evaluated. What makes it hard to see the problem is that even typing it in LaTeX chooses the interpretation. But what would $\bar{} L^*$ mean?

Comment: @HendrikJan "But what would ${}^-L^*$ mean?" That seems completely hypothetical and not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

For any language $L$ over alphabet $\Sigma$,

- $\overline{L} = \Sigma^*\setminus L$ is the complement of $L$: the set of $\Sigma$-strings *not* in $L$;
- $L^*$ is the *Kleene closure* of $L$: the set of strings $w\in\Sigma^*$ such that we can write $w=w_1\dots w_k$ for some $k\geq 0$ such that each $w_i\in L$.  For example, if $L$ is the set of English words, then [correcthorsebatterystaple](https://xkcd.com/936/) is in $L^*$.

Now, $\overline{L}^*$ is something-star, where "something" is $\overline{L}$. That is, it's the Kleene closure of the complement of $L$: the set of all strings $w\in\Sigma^*$ that can be written $w_1\dots w_k$ such that each $w_i$ is *not* in $L$. Essentially, we read left-to-right, so you parse "$\overline{L}$" before you reach the star.

Conversely, $\overline{L^*}$ is something-complement, where "something" is $L^*$, the Kleene closure of $L$. That is, it is the set of all strings that *cannot* be written $w_1\dots w_k$ where each $w_i\in L$.

These are not necessarily the same languages. For example, consider $\Sigma=\{1\}$ and $L=\{11\}$.  Then $1\in\overline{L}$, so $\overline{L}^*=\Sigma^*$. However, $$\overline{L^*} = \overline{\{1^i\mid i\text{ is even}\}} = \{1^i\mid i\text{ is odd}\}\neq\Sigma^*\,.$$